# Is it Good Practice to use return in onClick in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, function

On one of my PRs, my colleague comment to use return before these functions call is it a good practice to use return in onClick.

Note: these functions do not return anything.

```
onClick={() => {
  if (isPlatform) {
    handlePlatformChange({ selectedPlatform: item, selectedTab: index });
  } else if (isExecution) {
    handleExecutionMode(item);
  } else {
    handleBrowserChange([item], index);
  }
 }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is any problem with returning in `onClick`.

I do agree that it would be more convenient to read if you would return.

For example :

```
onClick={() => {
  if (isPlatform) {
    return handlePlatformChange({ selectedPlatform: item, selectedTab: index });
  }
  if (isExecution) return handleExecutionMode(item);
  return handleBrowserChange([item], index);
 }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know it's an opinionated thing but I 100% agree that this is more readable than a bunch of else if statements.

Comment: thanx for a prompt response, I'll update it definitely (Y)